Excel: Linebreak after 3 Commas
I have a cell with a content like:
2,1.5,2,3,1,2,4,3.1,2.1,9

What I need is to add a linebreak after every 3rd comma, like:
2,1.5,2,
3,1,2,
4,3.1,2.1,
9

Can this be done with a formular (not Visual Basic)?

Here is one method which doesn't uses any LAMBDA() helper function instead using TEXTSPLIT()+HSTACK()+TEXTJOIN()


• Formula used in cell A3
=TEXTJOIN(HSTACK(",",",",","&CHAR(10)),1,TEXTSPLIT(A1,","))


Once the formula is applied please remember to hit ALT+H+W or select the cell and from Home Tab select the wrap cells.

Or, just paste the following:
=TEXTJOIN({",",",",",
"},1,TEXTSPLIT(A1,","))


Additionally, can use the following as mentioned by VBasic2008 Sir
=LET(
     data,A2:A11,
     del,",",
     del_count,3,
     r_del,CHAR(10),
     MAP(data,LAMBDA(m,TEXTJOIN(HSTACK(EXPAND(del,,del_count-1,del),del&r_del),,TEXTSPLIT(m,del)))))



I was thinking there must be easier way. You make it simpler.

@Harun24hr Dada, you forced me to do it , I was going to post the same answer like yours initially

Always good to see simpler and easier solution. Appreciate always.

Superb. Still can't believe that it works. Here's just a more dynamic version. Maybe you want to improve and add it to your post: =LET(data,A2:A11,del,",",del_count,3,r_del,CHAR(10),MAP(data,LAMBDA(m,TEXTJOIN(HSTACK(EXPAND(del,,del_count-1,del),del&r_del),,TEXTSPLIT(m,del))))).

Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, my Excel gives an error on HSTACK. It seems that this function only applies to Office 365 (me using Office 2021 - sorry, should have said this, I didn't realise there was so much different between the 2 versions).

@Werner this should do the trick for you: =TEXTJOIN({",",",",", "},1,FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b")) or =TEXTJOIN(CHOOSE({1,2,3},",",",",","&CHAR(10)),1,FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"))

Well caught TEXTJOIN! While using of an array of delimiters is not specified in the Syntax, it's provided in the third example.

=TEXTJOIN({",",",",""},,TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")) where the 3rd string is not empty, but a manual line break (alt+enter, or new line on mobile)

One way could be-
=TEXTJOIN(","&CHAR(10),1,BYROW(WRAPROWS(TEXTSPLIT(A1,","),3,""),LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(",",1,r))))



Can't improve on @Mayukh's answer, but here is a regex for variety:
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(([\d\.]+,){3})","$1\n")

and wrap as before.

Note:
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"((?:[\d\.]+,){3})","$1\n")

with the inner group flagged as non-capturing would be more obvious to me, but the slightly shorter version does work as you can see from the screenshot above. The output from Regex101 is:

